# Powershell: Removing duplicate shortcuts containing its name and a number incremented in Desktop

Tags: windows, powershell

I need some help in getting rid of duplicate shortcuts containing the name of the shortcut followed by an incremented number (1)

This is the code I currently have

```
$cache = Get-ChildItem $env:OneDriveCommercial\Desktop
    if ($cache) {
        $cache | Where {(($_.Name -like "*.lnk") -or ($_.Name -like "*.url")) -and ($_.Name -like "*- Copy*")} | Remove-Item -Force
        $cache | Where {(($_.Name -like "*.lnk") -or ($_.Name -like "*.url")) -and ($_.Name -like "*-WAV-D-*")} | Remove-Item -Force
        $cache | Where {(($_.Name -like "*.lnk") -or ($_.Name -like "*.url")) -and ($_.Name -like "*-WAV-L-*")} | Remove-Item -Force
        $cache | Where {(($_.Name -like "*.lnk") -or ($_.Name -like "*.url")) -and ($_.Name -like "*-WSC-L-*")} | Remove-Item -Force
        $cache | Where {(($_.Name -like "*.lnk") -or ($_.Name -like "*.url")) -and ($_.Name -like "*-WSC-D-*")} | Remove-Item -Force
        $cache | Where {(($_.Name -like "*.lnk") -or ($_.Name -like "*.url")) -and ($_.Name -like "*Shortcut*")} | Remove-Item -Force
    } else {
        exit 0
    }
```

This gets rid of most icons but I am having issues with icons that have the name of the file and then an incremented number like for example AR Reader.url(1), AR Reader.url(2). These are not getting removed and sometimes I have over 100 of these icons and do not know how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you not just extend the where query

```
$cache = Get-ChildItem $env:OneDriveCommercial\Desktop
    if ($cache) {
        $cache | Where {
        (($_.Name -like "*.lnk") -or ($_.Name -like "*.url") -or ($_.Name -like "*.lnk(*)") -or ($_.Name -like "*.url(*)")) -and 
        (($_.Name -like "*- Copy*") -or ($_.Name -like "*-WAV-D-*") -or ($_.Name -like "*-WAV-L-*") -or ($_.Name -like "*-WSC-L-*") -or ($_.Name -like "*-WSC-D-*") -or ($_.Name -like "*Shortcut*"))
        } | Remove-Item -Force
    } else {
        exit 0
    }
```